# Group by combined with matching

Tags: r, group-by, matching, fill

Small rep of my data set:

```
TEAM1 <- c("ATL", "CHI", "CLE", "DET", "GSW", "NOP", "BKN","ATL", "PHI","CHI")
HOME.AWAY <- c("vs.", "vs.", "@", "@", "vs.", "@", "vs.","vs.", "@","@")
TEAM2 <- c("DET", "CLE", "CHI", "ATL", "NOP", "GSW", "CHI","PHI", "ATL","BKN")
DATE <- as.Date(c("2015-05-14", "2015-05-14", "2015-05-14",
           "2015-05-14","2015-05-14", "2015-05-14", "2015-05-15","2015-05-15",
           "2015-05-15","2015-05-15"))
PTS <- c(94, 97, 95, 106, 111, 95, 100,112,87, 94)
df <- data.frame(TEAM1,HOME.AWAY,TEAM2,PTS,DATE)

df

   TEAM1 HOME.AWAY TEAM2 PTS       DATE
   ATL       vs.   DET  94 2015-05-14
   CHI       vs.   CLE  97 2015-05-14
   CLE         @   CHI  95 2015-05-14
   DET         @   ATL 106 2015-05-14
   GSW       vs.   NOP 111 2015-05-14
   NOP         @   GSW  95 2015-05-14
   BKN       vs.   CHI 100 2015-05-15
   ATL       vs.   PHI 112 2015-05-15
   PHI         @   ATL  87 2015-05-15
   CHI       vs.   BKN  94 2015-05-15
```

The dataframe is organized by team level. So each game, will create two rows of data. For example, Atlanta vs Detroit (first row) and Detroit vs Atlanta (fourth row). The dataframe then includes the boxscore (PTS, REB, AST...) for the TEAM1. For this example I only included the Points scored variable. I would like to create a new variable that was "Points scored by the opponent team".

Output would look like this:

```
   TEAM1 HOME.AWAY TEAM2 PTS       DATE  PTS.OPPT
   ATL       vs.   DET  94 2015-05-14    106
   CHI       vs.   CLE  97 2015-05-14    95
   CLE         @   CHI  95 2015-05-14    97
   DET         @   ATL 106 2015-05-14    94
   GSW       vs.   NOP 111 2015-05-14    95
   NOP         @   GSW  95 2015-05-14    111
   BKN       vs.   CHI 100 2015-05-15    94
   ATL       vs.   PHI 112 2015-05-15    87
   PHI         @   ATL  87 2015-05-15    112
   CHI       vs.   BKN  94 2015-05-15    100
```

I tried using group by date and then some sort of matching by couldn't just figure out the matching part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> TEAM1 <- c("ATL", "CHI", "CLE", "DET", "GSW", "NOP", "BKN","ATL", "PHI","CHI")
> HOME.AWAY <- c("vs.", "vs.", "@", "@", "vs.", "@", "vs.","vs.", "@","@")
> TEAM2 <- c("DET", "CLE", "CHI", "ATL", "NOP", "GSW", "CHI","PHI", "ATL","BKN")
> DATE <- as.Date(c("2015-05-14", "2015-05-14", "2015-05-14",
+                   "2015-05-14","2015-05-14", "2015-05-14", "2015-05-15","2015-05-15",
+                   "2015-05-15","2015-05-15"))
> PTS <- c(94, 97, 95, 106, 111, 95, 100,112,87, 94)
> df <- data.frame(TEAM1,HOME.AWAY,TEAM2,PTS,DATE)
> 
> df<-merge(df, df,  by.x=c("TEAM1", "TEAM2", "DATE"), by.y=c("TEAM2", "TEAM1", "DATE"))
> df<-df[,c("TEAM1", "HOME.AWAY.x", "TEAM2", "PTS.x","DATE", "PTS.y" )]
> names(df)<-c("TEAM1", "HOME.AWAY", "TEAM2","PTS", "DATE", "PTS.OPPT")
> df
   TEAM1 HOME.AWAY TEAM2 PTS       DATE PTS.OPPT
1    ATL       vs.   DET  94 2015-05-14      106
2    ATL       vs.   PHI 112 2015-05-15       87
3    BKN       vs.   CHI 100 2015-05-15       94
4    CHI         @   BKN  94 2015-05-15      100
5    CHI       vs.   CLE  97 2015-05-14       95
6    CLE         @   CHI  95 2015-05-14       97
7    DET         @   ATL 106 2015-05-14       94
8    GSW       vs.   NOP 111 2015-05-14       95
9    NOP         @   GSW  95 2015-05-14      111
10   PHI         @   ATL  87 2015-05-15      112
```

Comment: can you just explain what your first line of code do?

Comment: Merge is similar to SQL join operation. It basically combines two data sets  using  some  conditions, in this case the condition is that x.TEAM1=y.TEAM2 and  x.TEAM2=y.TEAM1 and x.DATE=y.DATE.  This  is actually special case of join - self join, because  both datasets are the same.  Normally you  use merge  operation to join different data sets.